# Facing the issue with the UTC date format, using setdateformat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, timezone-offset, unparseable

I've updated few jars dependency and created the war. In the new war getting the issue-

> Unparseable date format -"2023-08-30T01:30:00.000+00:00" and working 2023-08-30T01:30:00.000+0000"

UTC offset issue- `2023-08-30T01:30:00.000+00:00` the `+0000` in the end is working but not the `+00:00`. Some parsing has been changed what it looks like as with previous version working and with new getting error because of `+00:00` is coming.

But when I rollback with the older one it was working fine. So, I suspect it is because of some jar update.
Update few jars- mysqlconnector version, hibernateORM, bouncycastle, and few others but don't know which is causing this issue

I tried to check which jar is causing this issue but didn't get anything yet to know what is causing the issue. Guessing any jar is causing the issue. New to all this and might be information is not sufficient. Any idea may help.

Comment: How does the affected Java code look?

Comment: There was no code changes except the jars version update in pom.xml

Comment: We don't know which jar you updated. Please add more info.

Comment: Updated mysql-connector-java version from 8.0.19 to 8.0.33. Though others as mentioned in the question also being updated but I suspect this one and hibernateORM which is update to 5.3.20.Final from 4.3.11.Final

Comment: UTC offset issue- 2023-08-30T01:30:00.000+00:00 the +0000 in the end is working but not the +00:00. Some parsing has been changed what it looks like as with previous version working and with new getting error because of +00:00 is coming. Can someone guide how can I identify

Comment: Take more care in formatting your post to Stack Overflow. I cleaned up this one for you this time.

Comment: Impossible to say. Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: Yes, but not much

Comment: I added this property: spring.jackson.datr-format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ, and it worked but now getting another issue - Cannot deserialize value of type java.util.date from string "some value" not a valid representation. Failed to par se Date value

Comment: This is coming after jackson version update from 2.9.5 to 2.15.2. Added the above property but it is not solving my problem. Any other suggestion?